# Boxplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do box plots from data frame. I have two columns, one with countries the other with data concerning those countries.

```
       Country  AverageTemperatureCelsius          
0  New Zealand                     11.059      
1  Columbia                        11.327      
2  New Zealand                     11.585                 
3  Columbia                        11.432
4  New Zealand                     12.707
```

I want to do boxplots where one will represent the New Zeland and the other will represent Columbia. (of course I have more countries in real data).

I managed to solve my own problem the solution is

```
    newdf=df.pivot(columns='Country', values='AverageTemperatureCelsius')
    plt.xlim((0,9))
    i=0
    for column in newdf.columns:
        plt.boxplot(newdf[column][newdf[column].notnull()], positions=[i+1],widths=0.5)
        i=i+1
```

Comment: they will stack on top of one another because it's the same x-axis, e.g New Zealand or Columbia. What exactly do you want to plot? 3 bars for NewZealand and 2bars for Columbia?

Comment: I will add the expected output and am sorry, because I confused bar plots with box...

Answer (score 0):

Using seaborn might be the quickest way:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['New Zealand','Columbia','New Zealand','Columbia','New Zealand'],
                  'AverageTemperatureCelsius':[11.059,11.327,11.585,11.432,12.707] })
sns.boxplot(x='Country',y='AverageTemperatureCelsius', data=df)
```

[image]